# Almost working PDF merge batch file, just a little help needed

Tags: pdf, batch-file

I'm using this batch file to merge PDF files, and it's working, but only with files which don't have spaces in their names. For a 'test file.pdf' it gives an error ~ can't find file test and file.pdf. With what should I replace the "*.PDF" to get it to work correctly?

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%A IN ("*.PDF") DO (set command=!command! %%A)
%~dp0\pdftk.exe %command% cat output "%~dp1merged_PDF.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `set command=!command! %%A` with `set "command=!command! "%%~A""`.

For naming the merged file after its parent folder you can determine the parent folder name like this:

```
for %%a in ("%~dp1.") do set "name=%%~nxa"
```

and then create the output file like this:

```
%~dp0\pdftk.exe %command% cat output "%~dp1%name%.pdf"
```

Comment: Great, only one little thing more. How do I rename the merged_PDF.pdf file after it's parent folder?